# How to install Selenium on Anaconda and How to use selenium with Scrapy on Spyder IDE of Anaconda?

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy, anaconda, spyder

I have searched a lot on google but couldn't find any helpful post and wondering like how to install selenium on Anaconda and then afterward How to use selenium along with Scrapy on Spyder IDE of anaconda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an awefully broad question. Since it is not possible to write a whole tutorial here, I can give you the first steps:

Installing selenium can be done by `conda install -c conda-forge selenium`

After that you can use it in any python script. It doesn't matter which IDE you use or if you use an interactive session. Make sure though that Spider is set to use the same python version that you installed selenium for.

For the basic usage of Selenium and Scrapy, you should follow the basic tutorials [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#simple-usage) and [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/overview.html). If you have more specific questions, you should open a new question that shows your attempt at a script, what you expect it to do, the error/output you are getting instead etc.

Comment: I have an another question like should I perform the above given commands on Anaconda Prompt or on Window's command prompt?
Actually the problem is I had only set the path of python 2.7 in the Advanced System Settings>Environment Variables and I have also separately installed Anaconda with python 3.6 in some directory and didn't set the path yet?

Comment: So I want to ask Can I set the path of Python 3.6 that's installed within Anaconda cloud at the same place or if yes then will it create problem using me my python 2.7 and all related with 2.7 version?

Comment: Before you get into a bigger mess: Delete the python2 version that is not from anaconda. Then you can create a virtual environment with python 2.7 using anaconda. Then you will have a much better seperation between the two versions. The difference between the Anaconda propmt and your windows cmd is that in the anaconda prompt all paths are set so you can use conda commands. If you have not added Anaconda to your PATH, then you need to run the commands above using the Anaconda Propmt

Comment: well, I'm confused a bit If I delete python2 version that is not from anaconda then how would I be able to create a virtual environment with python 2.7? How this will give a much better seperation between two versions if I delete the python2 version?

Comment: `conda create -n py27 python=2.7` is the command you would need to create the virtual environment. It doesn't matter that you have downlaoded and installed anaconda with python3, you can still create environments with any other python version. As to why it gives a much better seperation: by using virtual environments, you can alays be sure that after running `activate py27` every `python`/`pip`/`conda` command will be for that version/environment. In your current setup its easy to get confused which `pip`/`python` is being executed when in the command line. There are tons of questions

Comment: On here where ppl say that they cannot install a module and it turns out that all they had was a different python version that was confusing